# $L_p(\mu,X)$ is isometrically isomorphic to $\ell_p(X)$

Tags: analysis, measure-theory, banach-spaces, lp-spaces, vector-space-isomorphism

In the book [Banach Spaces of Vector-Valued Functions](https://books.google.com.br/books?id=lm57CwAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover#v=onepage&q&f=false) the authors present a *demonstration* for **Proposition 1.6.4**, [pages 32-33](https://books.google.com.br/books?id=lm57CwAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover#v=onepage&q=proposition%201.6.4&f=false):

> Let $1\le p \le + \infty$, if $(\Omega,\Sigma,\mu)$ is a $\sigma$-finite purely atomic measure space then $L_p(\mu,X)$ is isometrically isomorphic to $\ell_p(X)$.

Let $(A_n)$ be a sequence of pairwise disjoint atoms of $(\Omega,\Sigma,\mu)$ whose union is $\Omega$. Then the map

\begin{align}
   L_p(\mu,X) &\longrightarrow \ell_p(X)\\
f=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\chi_{A_n}(\cdot)x_n &\longrightarrow (\mu(A_n)^{\frac{1}{p}}x_n)_n
\end{align}

for $1\le p<\infty$, is a isometric isomorphism onto.

I am having difficulty understanding this map and consequently seeing that it is an isomorphism. $x_n$ is the point in $A_n$?

Comment: If $f \in L_p$, then $x_n$ is just the value of $f$ on $A_n$.

Comment: @TheoreticalEconomist Why have $(\cdot)$?

Answer (score 2):

If $A$ is an atom then any measurable function $f$ on $A$ is a.e. constant on $A$. Proof: Consider $f^{-1}([\frac {i-1} 2,\frac  i 2)$. These form a a partition of $A$. By definition of an atom it follows that $f$ takes values in $[\frac {i_1-1} 2,\frac  {i_1} 2)$ for some $i_1$. Next look at $f^{-1}([\frac {i_1-1} {2^{2}},\frac  {i_1}  {2^{2}})$ and so on. You will see that $f$ takes values in a decreasing sequence of  intervals $I_1,I_2,...$ with length of $I_n$ tending to $0$. There is  a unique point $x$ in the intersection of these intervals and $f=x$ a.e.

Going back to the proof it is straightforward to compute the norm of $(\mu(A_n)^{1/n}x_n)_n$ in $\ell^{p}(X)$ and show that it is equal to norm of $f$.